# Why does refreshing a page with a google map often fail?

Tags: google-maps, refresh

I'm working on a website that needs google maps, and testing is being a bitch because refreshing the page very often fails (hangs endlessly) so I need to go to a different page and come back in order to test the new version of the code. I have noticed that refreshing the page only fails on pages with maps, so I'm guessing these are related. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to startup Firebug in Firefox and see if there's any Javascript errors coming up in the console?  Sometimes they can cause otherwise undetectable "hanging" on pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you may have a javascript error, which can be checked using the error console(ctrl+j) or firebug.

Are you using API v2 or v3?

The problem may be, if you're using v2, that it's simply too large to keep reloading.  The v2 API loads a LOT of functionality through the code given, while v3 has less built-in features, but boasts a much MUCH quicker load time.

I've worked with both and found that v3 tends to work much more smoothly, if you only require a relatively simple map.